# Passing data from one jframe to another jframe java

Tags: java

I have two JFrames.One Jframe has one Jtabel , when i selectedrow and press the JButton, second Jframe set string acd get text from jframe1

code in jframe1

```
    int i = tblschdule.getSelectedRow() ;
    String a = (String) tblschdule.getValueAt(i, 0) ;
    String b = (String) tblschdule.getValueAt(i, 1) ;
    Fisimonitoring form1 = new Fisimonitoring();
    form1.acd=a;
    form1.setVisible(true);
```

jframe2

```
  public String acd;
```

code form1.acd=a; not work, String acd always null. how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

your question is very incomplete bt here is an example to send data to another
frame

```
//a jframe
public class Aframe extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private Bframe bframe;
    private void sendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        if (bframe==null) {
            bframe = new Bframe();
        }
        String text = jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(),jTable1.getSelectedColumn()).toString();
        bframe.setText(text);
        bframe.setVisible(true);
    }                                    
}


//b jframe
public class Bframe extends javax.swing.JFrame {
 public void setText(String text){
    this.textField.setText(text);
    }
}
```

in your case if you have already opened `Bjframe` you should make sure that `same instance` of `Bjframe` is shared by `Ajframe`.

Comment: code in jframe1" form1.acd=a;" not work, String acd in jframe2 always null. how to solve it ?

Comment: try printing out the String a maybe you are not getting a value from the table

Answer (score 0):

It's quiet late for this answer but the solution for your problem is pretty simple.
You Need to send the value across the frame's.

Like if you are on jFrame1 and on click you are calling JFrame2

```
function actionPerformedOnButtonClick(){

 String text = valueOfTheLabel;
 new YourFrameName(text).setVisible(true); 
}
```

And on JFrame2, You need to write a parameterized contructor like this..

```
 public JFrame2(String textFromFrame1) {
    initComponents();
}
```

And You can Access It on Frame2.